Cake baking in gas oven - uneven
Baked 3 layers in identical pans with weighed equal batter on center shelf.  2 front layers overflowed bake pan and #3 at center back rose unevenly.  Tested done with toothpick and all fell drastically out of oven when cooling. 2 layers very lopsided when removed from pans.  Did wrap each pan with wet cloth to achieve equal rise and bake -understand cakes bake outside to center - wet cloth used to equalize bake.  I have photos.  Before repeating bake, plan to test oven temps in 3 spots with 3 oven thermometers to see if there are hot/cool spots.

3 layers on one shelf? that, by itself, will tend to make any non-convection (non-fan) oven bake unevenly.
